# Differentiate Past Events from Future Events

Tags: ruby-on-rails

QUESTION: How do I show events that have `start_time<time.now` & `start_time>time.now` in two different tables?

I have `scaffold event start_time:datetime title`

Events_controller:

```
def index
  @event = Event.all
end
```

index.html.haml:

```
 %table
    %thead
      %tr
        %th Start_time
        %th Title

    %tbody
      - @events.each do |event|
        %tr
          %td= event.start_time
          %td= event.title
```

thank you:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a possible solution. with two query...

Controller

```
 def index
    @upcoming_events = Event.where("start_time > ?", Time.now)
    @past_events = Event.where("start_time < ?", Time.now)
 end
```

View

```
   %table
        %thead
          %tr
            %th Start_time
            %th Title

        %tbody
          - @upcoming_events.each do |event|
            %tr
              %td= event.start_time
              %td= event.title


%table
    %thead
      %tr
        %th Start_time
        %th Title

    %tbody
      - @past_events.each do |event|
        %tr
          %td= event.start_time
          %td= event.title
```

Answer (score 2):

You may simply define `scopes` for the past and future events:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :in_the_past, { where('start_time < ?', Time.now }
  scope :in_the_future, { where('start_time > ?', Time.now }
end
```

Then your views will be:

**_events_table.html.haml**

```
%table
  %thead
    %tr
      %th Start_time
      %th Title

   %tbody
    - events.find_each do |event|
      %tr
        %td= event.start_time
        %td= event.title
```

**index.html.haml**

```
/ Past events
= render 'events_table', events: Event.in_the_past
/ Future events
= render 'events_table', events: Event.in_the_future
```

Comment: Nope, but it is reusable!

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Enumerable#partition`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition) to divide your events into buckets.

```
past, future = Event.all.partition { |e| e.start_time < Time.now }
```

Comment: that's interesting

Answer (score 0):

If you are not bothering about performance and you're ok with 2 SQL queries, then I'd suggest something like that:

```
def index
  @past_events = Event.where('start_time < ?', Time.zone.now)
  @future_events = Event.where('start_time > ?', Time.zone.now)
end
```

Comment: Might want to make one of those have `=` in it, or you could potentially omit things that start right now.